# How can I execute druid query using cURL command in a Python script?

Tags: python, curl, druid

I need to run the Druid query in a Python script using the cURL command. I am able to get the result in the terminal like the one below. I am a novice in Python.

This is what I can do in the terminal.

`curl 'http://druid.domain.vpc/druid/v2/sql' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"query":"Select * from demo_table"}'`

Here is result

`[{"__time":"2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","account_algorithm_id":"","account_id":"008be-44ad","action":"attribution","browser_platform":"","browser_type":"","sft_link_id":"","link_index":"","link_url":"","template_version":"","bucket_id":"23-4032-91ca-506bd","campaign_id":"3745e5a2-1-9582-2456bd7","count":1,"creative_id":"ef-4958-8d84-8","email_domain":"","event":"purchased initial","experiment_id":"51bd7d6e-5cb3-44ce-f445973","extended_attributes.aid":"","extended_attributes.atype":"","extended_attributes.aid":"","extended_attributes.ink_index":"","extended_attributes.plate_version":"","extended_attributes.cloud_app":"","extended_attributes.domain_region":"","extended_attributes.is_global":"","extended_attributes.opened_by":"","extended_attributes.sms_type":"","is_duplicate":"","message_distinct":"\"AgEHDAMMAAA=\"","mime_type":"","revenue_sum":0.0,"trigger_type":"EmailTrigger","trigger_uuid":"89055b76-0620","user_count":"\"AQAAAQB3AQ==\"","user_distinct":"\"AgEHDAAA=\""}]`

I want to run a druid query in my Python script. I am trying to achieve this using the cURL command within my Python script. Then I need to parse the output data into a CSV file Can someone, please help

Comment: Do not try to excute curl into a Python script, instead use a Python native HTTP client. The `request` (https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library can help you with that

Comment: @Layo you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a set of examples from the Apache Druid project on how to use the Druid APIs from python using the `requests` package.

https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/examples/quickstart/jupyter-notebooks/notebooks/04-api/00-getting-started.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

If you are **100% percent sure every system where the script will run will have `curl` installed and callable** then...
you can use `os.system()` to send a command to the system where the script is running to run the curl command you provided and then save the result to text. Then following that you can then use Python to read and parse as you see fit. This illustrates through to the reading the text file part, as I think it would work given what you provided (see below):

```py
import os
s = """curl 'http://druid.domain.vpc/druid/v2/sql' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"query":"Select * from demo_table"}' > curl_result.txt"""
os.system(s)
with open("curl_result.txt", 'r') as file_read_handler:
    for line in file_read_handler:
        print(line)
```

I think that should result in showing what you show in your second block if the curl command actually works to retrieve the content. In my test, the curl command tried to run but said `Could not resolve host: druid.domain.vpc`, and so it didn't work. That may be because either where I'm running it has the port/socket necessary blocked or the other end has an issue at the time.
Or possibly what you provided isn't a minimal reproducible example. And that may be because finding a sql database to query as a toy example is difficult?